# XSL to HTML - Insert Image

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I am making a XSL (to be converted to HTML) file from XML and i want to insert an image. My problem is that the link of the image is in the XML. I want the image from "caixa id="102"". How can i do it?

XML:

```
<loja xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="trabalhoXSD.xsd">
<componentesDisponiveis>
    <caixa id="101">
        <preco>23.90</preco>
        <imagem>https://www.pcdiga.com/bizizi/img_upload/produtos_1/18677_1_gx.jpg?d=1443548409</imagem>
        <descricao>A Nox introduz a Kore: uma solução com amplas possibilidades num formato semi-tower. A sua versatilidade converte-a numa opção perfeita para aqueles que 
            necessitam de uma caixa para hardware de alto desempenho, num formato mais compacto.
            O design em preto com linhas angulares fornecem-lhe um aspecto implacável, juntamente com o efeito de alumínio escovado do painel frontal.</descricao>
        <HDD>5</HDD>
        <SDD>1</SDD>
        <leitorDiscosOpticos>0</leitorDiscosOpticos>
    </caixa>
    <caixa id="102">
        <preco>124.89</preco>
        <imagem>https://www.pcdiga.com/bizizi/img_upload/produtos_1/8502_1_gx.png?d=1348685644</imagem>
        <descricao>Quando você precisar de sair e levar seu jogo, a caixa Vengeance C70 é a opção perfeita. Ela é esculpida em aço sólido e feito para sobreviver a viagens com 
            menos desgaste, e as alças para transporte ergonómico acrescentam confiança ao transporte.</descricao>
        <HDD>8</HDD>
        <SDD>1</SDD>
        <leitorDiscosOpticos>0</leitorDiscosOpticos>
    </caixa></componentesDisponiveis></loja>
```

Comment: You want to insert image where? Please post your XSLT so far, and the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

Image sources, like other HTML attributes, need to be added using the `<xsl:attribute>` tag.

```
<img>
    <xsl:attribute name="src">
        <xsl:value-of select="componentesDisponiveis/caixa[@id = '102']/imagem"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
</img>
```

As you can see to get the specific Id you just add it between square brackets as a condition.